# Record not getting locked using Approval.lock apex

Tags: apex, approval-process, locking

My requirement is to make a record read only when value of a field changes to 'Inactive'.

I read that records can be locked using approval.lock in Apex.

Hence, I was trying to use Approval.lock record apex to lock the record. The record is getting locked but it's still editable. The profile is not Sys Admin and it does not have Modify All Data permission.

Also, the object doesn't have any approval process. I'm just locking the record using Apex.

Any ideas why the record is still editable ?

Avinash

Comment: Can you check the results? `Approval.LockResult result = Approval.lock(recordId);
System.debug(result.isSuccess());
System.debug(result.getErrors());` See what you get in the debug logs. We can help you from there.

Comment: Figured out the issue. The issue was that the user was having 'Modify All' on the object. After removing that, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The issue was that the user was having 'Modify All' on the object. After removing that, it worked.